# Updating an object property in a nested collection with another property of this object in MongoDB with c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to update property in **nested** collection. All examples describes about setting concrete value, but not about value from another field.

MongoDB version: 4.2

C# driver version: 2.10.4

Product example:

```
    {
     _id: "1",
     Title: "Some title",
     Price: 20,
     OriginalPrice: 10,
     ... other props ...
     Variants: 
      [
        {
           Price: 21,
           OriginalPrice: 11
           ... other props ...
        },
        {
           Price: 22,
           OriginalPrice: 13
           ... other props ...
        },
      ] 
    }
```

I know how to update `Price`

```
var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<Product, Product>.Create("{'$set': {'Price': '$OriginalPrice'}}");
productCollection.UpdateMany(FilterDefinition<Product>.Empty, Builders<Product>.Update.Pipeline(pipeline));
```

But how i can update `Variants.Price` as `Variants.OriginalPrice`? Trying

```
var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<Product, Product>.Create("{'$set': {'Price': '$OriginalPrice', 'Variants.$[].Price': '$Variants.$[].OriginalPrice'}}");
productCollection.UpdateMany(FilterDefinition<Product>.Empty, Builders<Product>.Update.Pipeline(pipeline));
```

but an error occured.

**Upd 1**: Variant contains other properties.

@Mickl's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62912454/4527678) is the solution, but

**Is overwriting the entire nested collection the most optimal way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right handside of your update expression needs to be a MongoDB aggregate expression[1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/index.html) and currently you're using the regular "update" syntax. Based on the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/index.html):

> Specify the name of each field to add and set its value to an aggregation expression. For more information on expressions, see Expressions

The [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) operator can be used to achieve what you want:

```
var set = @"{
         $set:
            {
                Variants:
                {
                    $map:
                    {
                        input: '$Variants',
                            in: { $mergeObjects: [ '$$this', { Price: '$$this.OriginalPrice' } ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }";

var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<Product, Product>.Create(set);

var res = productCollection.UpdateMany(FilterDefinition<Product>.Empty, Builders<Product>.Update.Pipeline(pipeline));
```

Comment: Thanks @mickl! Nice approach with map. Is there a better solution without rewriting all nested Variants collection if i have many other properties in variant object? What if variant object contains different properties in other documents?

Comment: @EvgenyIvanov of course, you can use `$mergeObjects`. See my modified answer

Comment: thanks, just found this solution and update in question :) Is overwriting the entire nested collection the most optimal way?

Comment: @EvgenyIvanov I believe so