# MongoDb C# driver - version 4.2.1 Adding new field using aggregate pipeline throws exception

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to add a new field to the documents in a collection - if the field doesn't already exist. According to MongoDb shell I am using version 4.2.1 with C# MongoDb.Driver v2.9.2
However, the following code throws an exception with the message: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command update failed: BSON field 'update.updates.u' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'"

```
var filterNoRequiredField = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("RequiredFiled", false);

var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<BsonDocument>()
    .AppendStage(
    "{ $set: { RequiredField: 'Hello World'} }",
    BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance);

collection.UpdateMany(filterNoRequiredField, pipeline)
```

I'm using the aggregate pipeline as the task I actually want to achieve is a little more complicated, however I can't get past this first step. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code works for me but you can try using `Builders` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62909340/updating-an-object-property-in-a-nested-collection-with-another-property-of-this/62912454#62912454

Comment: Thanks Mickl, The real issue for me is I am trying to unit test the code using Mongo2go which I think is only 4.0 compatible. Knowing the code worked for you helped me understand I wasn't doing something fundamentally wrong code wise. That made me realise it was down to the other dependency.